# legacy studio cognos v12.0

Tags: version, cognos

I am reaching out to you regarding the recent announcement regarding the end of support for IBM Cognos Query Studio, Analysis Studio, and Workspace in version 11.2.4 of Cognos Analytics.

I understand that this final version, including these studios, will still receive the support and availability that we have always had. However, it is clear that we need to start planning the upgrade to Cognos Analytics 11.2.4 to ensure the continuity of our operations.

However, we are aware that this upgrade also entails a transition regarding our current processes and usage of the mentioned studios. Therefore, we would like to develop a plan to help us navigate this transition smoothly.

Could you please let me know what alternatives are available and how they differ from the Legacy Studio? Additionally, I would like to know how the migration of my existing projects from the Legacy Studio to the new version will be carried out.

Would it be possible to discuss this matter in more detail? We would like to explore the available options and benefit from your expertise to guide us throughout this process.